# Маппинг данных в @apollo/client react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

Подскажите пожалуйста, как корректно взять данные из кэша и провести над ними какие-то операции и вернуть в ui? Я имею в виду то, как мы делаем через селекторы в редаксе. Пробовал через resolvers, но результата не дало - не смог получить загруженные данные в самом резолвере

Answer (score 0):

нашел ответ, в apollo3 все это происходит через typePolicy - мы можем либо переопределить в каком виде будет возвращаться массив, либо определить новое свойство для этого [image: введите сюда описание изображения]